# Stylus file giving a failure to load resource error after I use css2stylus

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, stylus

I'm trying to use stylus for my nodeJs app with express, but the the browser is failing to compile my stylus file into css. Here is my style.styl file (the style.css file works when I don't use stylus at all). I converted css into stylus using the css2stylus module.

https://jsbin.com/qukasutawe/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 1):

You got a Stylus file with errors. I guess you used css2stylus.com, this site has bugs with `@media` and `@keyframes`. Try to convert your CSS with official CSS to Stylus conversion tool:

```
stylus --css your-file.css
```

The result of this conversion will be saved in `your-file.styl`.

Comment: The new files are still giving me an error 500 when I run it again though.

Comment: My app.js works when it's just css file, but here it is anyway. Thank you very much for your help!